# How to download macOS-Catalina-10.15

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm looking to download a macOS-Catalina-10.15 but can't find it anywhere on the web nor the apple website. Could anyone help find a safe site, preferably apple to download? Thanks.

I have a Macbook-Pro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mr. Macintosh](https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-download-macos-catalina-mojave-or-high-sierra-full-installers/) lists 8 ways of getting macOS installers. All get them from Apple though some involve running scripts to make it easier. I suggest one of these:

Method 1. The easiest way (if your Mac is eligible) is via the App Store.

Method 8: Direct Apple links to some installers.

Method 5: For myself, I often the Mac Deploy Stick (MDS).  This is 3rd party software (aimed at those who administer many MACs), but inspects what is available from Apple and downloads what you choose.

But select a method for yourself. All download from Apple.

Comment: Kudos to this answer. This Q may be marked as a dupe, but as a developer who wants convenient access to specific OS installer versions, this link is more useful to me than the answer on the "main" question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an official apple support page about the installation of older macOS versions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

There you can find a link for Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

To download MacOS Catalina, you need to search the App Store for Catalina and download/install it from there.